# tuple probleme with openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i need to create a loop for the table from excel file with openpyxl with the bellow code :

```
book_stock = load_workbook(r'\\file.xlsx')
    sheet_stock = book_stock.active

for row in range(2, sheet_stock.max_row+1):
        sheet_stock.cell(row=row, column=4).number_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

but i had this errer

`for one_row in range(2, wb_sheet.max_row+1): TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code ?  Have you defined range as a variable elsewhere ?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the the code sample so the sample is an example of the actual code causing the error?. It suggests you had assigned range as a variable (tuple) perhaps

Comment: @tomgalpin thank you for your comment, yes i have defined range as variable in enother  place of the code :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digesting the error:

```
   for one_row in range(2, wb_sheet.max_row+1) TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The error is showing that an object defined as a tuple is being called, in this case the object is "range".

Range is a Built-in Function, which is perfectly capable of being called in the way you have here.

The fact that you are getting this error strongly suggests that you have overwritten the builtin "range" and used it as a tuple previously in your code.

Simply rename the variable "range" which you have defined elsewhere as a tuple to something not reserved for the name of a builtin.